# preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, pcre

I'm trying to search a UTF8-encoded string using [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
preg_match('/H/u', "\xC2\xA1Hola!", $a_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $a_matches[0][1];
```

This should print 1, since "H" is at index 1 in the string "¡Hola!". But it prints 2. So it seems like it's not treating the subject as a UTF8-encoded string, even though I'm passing the "u" [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in the regular expression.

I have the following settings in my php.ini, and other UTF8 functions are working:

```
mbstring.func_overload = 7
mbstring.language = Neutral
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = pass
mbstring.http_output = pass
mbstring.encoding_translation = Off
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187615/utf-8-characters-in-preg-match-all-php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like this is a "feature", see
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37391

'u' switch only makes sense for pcre, PHP itself is unaware of it.

From PHP's point of view, strings are byte sequences and returning byte offset seems logical (i don't say "correct").

Comment: Great...and they don't provide a mb_preg_replace.

Comment: Be aware that the same "rules" regarding utf-8 handling applies to the 5th parameter `$offset`.
Sample: 
`var_dump(preg_match('/#/u', "\xc3\xa4#",$matches,0,2));`

Comment: php is aware of the u modifier it's listed in the manual see "u (PCRE_UTF8)"
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 52):

Although the *u* modifier makes both the pattern and subject be interpreted as UTF-8, the captured offsets are still counted in bytes.

You can use `mb_strlen` to get the length in UTF-8 characters rather than bytes:

```
$str = "\xC2\xA1Hola!";
preg_match('/H/u', $str, $a_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo mb_strlen(substr($str, 0, $a_matches[0][1]));
```

Comment: "The u modifier is only to get the pattern interpreted as UTF-8, not the subject." This is not true. Compare e.g. `preg_split('//', .)` with `preg_split('//u', .)`. Since this "x is interpret as UTF-8" is a bit vague, see [this](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) for the actual effects of the unicode mode.

Comment: According to http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#103348 the *u* modifier has effect on both the pattern **and the input**.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili Some people are of the opinion that it sucks at many things.

Comment: OK, php sucks at Unicode, but maybe with one constraint now: version<7.0. UString is coming https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ustring. UString aims to tackle the issues of working with Unicode strings

Comment: Fun fact, this produces different output depending upon your version. https://3v4l.org/iHl4a

Comment: @tomalak and next ones. Of course, php doesn't manage unicode, because it works on bytes if you use old functions like substr, strlen, etc., but it is fully managed since a very long time via the extension mbstring, enabled by default in many distributions and servers. This is a choice to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: I have had **NO TROUBLE** with UTF-8 in PHP since I started converting all my old sites to Unicode 4-5 years ago.

Comment: @Tomalak "Man, it's 2019 and PHP still sucks abysmally at Unicode." Please confirm.

Answer (score 29):

Try adding this **(*UTF8)** before the regex:

```
preg_match('(*UTF8)/H/u', "\xC2\xA1Hola!", $a_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Magic, thanks to a comment in
https://www.php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php#95828

Comment: Interesting, although I think you need the initial `/` before the `(*UTF8)`. This doesn't work on my system, but it might on others. What does this output when you do `echo $a_matches[0][1];`?

Comment: I used it like this on PHP 5.4.29, works like a charm:   

`preg_match_all('/(*UTF8)[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/', $txt, $matches);`

Comment: Doesn't work for me on either PHP 5.6 or PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04. `(*UTF8)` before delimiter is an error, after has no effect. I suspect that it depends on how/where you got your php, specifically the settings that `libpcre*` was compiled with.

Comment: Does not change the offsets for me, but that's an interesting thing to know. The original documentation for that "feature" is: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 9):

Excuse me for necroposting, but may be somebody will find it useful: code below can work both as replacement for preg_match and preg_match_all functions and returns correct matches with **correct** offset for UTF8-encoded strings.

```
     mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

     /**
     * Returns array of matches in same format as preg_match or preg_match_all
     * @param bool   $matchAll If true, execute preg_match_all, otherwise preg_match
     * @param string $pattern  The pattern to search for, as a string.
     * @param string $subject  The input string.
     * @param int    $offset   The place from which to start the search (in bytes).
     * @return array
     */
    function pregMatchCapture($matchAll, $pattern, $subject, $offset = 0)
    {
        $matchInfo = array();
        $method    = 'preg_match';
        $flag      = PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE;
        if ($matchAll) {
            $method .= '_all';
        }
        $n = $method($pattern, $subject, $matchInfo, $flag, $offset);
        $result = array();
        if ($n !== 0 && !empty($matchInfo)) {
            if (!$matchAll) {
                $matchInfo = array($matchInfo);
            }
            foreach ($matchInfo as $matches) {
                $positions = array();
                foreach ($matches as $match) {
                    $matchedText   = $match[0];
                    $matchedLength = $match[1];
                    $positions[]   = array(
                        $matchedText,
                        mb_strlen(mb_strcut($subject, 0, $matchedLength))
                    );
                }
                $result[] = $positions;
            }
            if (!$matchAll) {
                $result = $result[0];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $s1 = 'Попробуем русскую строку для теста';
    $s2 = 'Try english string for test';

    var_dump(pregMatchCapture(true, '/обу/', $s1));
    var_dump(pregMatchCapture(false, '/обу/', $s1));

    var_dump(pregMatchCapture(true, '/lish/', $s2));
    var_dump(pregMatchCapture(false, '/lish/', $s2));
```

Output of my example:

```php
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "обу"
          [1]=>
          int(4)
        }
      }
    }
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "обу"
        [1]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "lish"
          [1]=>
          int(7)
        }
      }
    }
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "lish"
        [1]=>
        int(7)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does instead of just pasting a code dump? And how does this answer the question?

Comment: It does exactly what described in comments and returns CORRECT string offsets. It is the subject of the question. No idea why I had -2 for my answer. It is working for me.

Comment: Well, that's why you should include an explanation of what your code does. People don't get what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Edit my answer, added tests.

Comment: To use `$offset` as `(characters)` instead of `(bytes)`, you can add this near the top of the function: `if ($offset) { $offset = strlen(mb_substr($subject, 0, $offset)); }`

Comment: Thanks. After searching on multiple questions, this is the only answer that does the trick.

Comment: An old comment of "necroposting", but still useful!  Thank you @GuyFawkes, this helped with my current mess of code I'm working through.  Cheers, jz

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the real UTF-8 offset by cutting the string to the offset returned by the `preg_mach` with the byte-counting `substr` and then measuring this prefix with the correct-counting `mb_strlen`.

```php
$utf8Offset = mb_strlen(substr($text, 0, $offsetFromPregMatch), 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is find the multi-byte safe position of H try mb_strpos()

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$str = "\xC2\xA1Hola!";
$pos = mb_strpos($str, 'H');
echo $str."\n";
echo $pos."\n";
echo mb_substr($str,$pos,1)."\n";
```

Output:

```
¡Hola!
1
H
```

Comment: That was just a simplified example, but this may be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote small class to convert offsets returned by preg_match to proper utf offsets:

```
final class NonUtfToUtfOffset
{
    /** @var int[] */
    private $utfMap = [];

    public function __construct(string $content)
    {
        $contentLength = mb_strlen($content);

        for ($offset = 0; $offset < $contentLength; $offset ++) {
            $char = mb_substr($content, $offset, 1);
            $nonUtfLength = strlen($char);

            for ($charOffset = 0; $charOffset < $nonUtfLength; $charOffset ++) {
                $this->utfMap[] = $offset;
            }
        }
    }

    public function convertOffset(int $nonUtfOffset): int
    {
        return $this->utfMap[$nonUtfOffset];
    }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
$content = 'aą bać d';
$offsetConverter = new NonUtfToUtfOffset($content);

preg_match_all('#(bać)#ui', $content, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($m[1] as [$word, $offset]) {
    echo "bad: " . mb_substr($content, $offset, mb_strlen($word))."\n";
    echo "good: " . mb_substr($content, $offsetConverter->convertOffset($offset), mb_strlen($word))."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/8Y32J

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx)  library.

```
pattern('/Hola/u')->match('\xC2\xA1Hola!')->first(function (Match $match) 
{
    echo $match->offset();     // characters
    echo $match->byteOffset(); // bytes
});
```

This `$match->offset()` is UTF-8 safe offset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved to me just by using casual **substr** instead of expected **mb_substr** (PHP 7.4).

The **mb_substr** together with **preg_match_all** /  PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE (despite using or not using */u* modifier)resulted in incorrect position when text contained euro sign symbol (€).

Also **iconv** and **utf8_encode** did not help, and I was not able to use **htmlentities**.

Just reverting to simple **substr** helped, and it worked with € and other characters correctly.