# Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, multibyte

There are no multibyte 'preg' functions available in PHP, so does that mean the default preg_functions are all mb safe? Couldn't find any mention in the php documentation.

Comment: I'm 90% sure the underlieing C functions are, but that doesn't mean the PHP versions are I suppose...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PCRE can support UTF-8 and other Unicode encodings, but it has to be specified at compile time. From the [man page for PCRE 8.0](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> The  current implementation of PCRE corresponds approximately with Perl 5.10, including support for UTF-8 encoded strings and  Unicode  general category  properties.  However,  UTF-8  and  Unicode  support has to be explicitly enabled; it is not the default. The  Unicode  tables  correspond to Unicode release 5.1.

PHP currently uses [PCRE 7.9](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/pcre/pcrelib/); your system might have an older version.

Taking a look at the [PCRE lib](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/pcre/pcrelib/config.h?view=markup&pathrev=PHP_5_2) that comes with PHP 5.2, it appears that it's configured to support Unicode properties and UTF-8. Same for the [5.3 branch](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/pcre/pcrelib/config.h?view=markup&pathrev=PHP_5_3).

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.0 which includes PCRE Version 7.9, I checked the PCRE config.h file which includes the UTF8 definition, so looks like the preg_funcs are safe.

Thanks very much for the info!

Comment: Is there a quick way to determine which version of PCRE an existing PHP installation is using? My server for instance is running PHP 5.5, but how can I tell what PCRE library it was compiled with?

Comment: As a note to anyone using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, the offset is in *bytes*, as such you'll want to use substr, not mb_substr and the like.

Answer (score 34):

pcre supports utf8 out of the box, see documentation for the 'u' modifier.

Illustration (\xC3\xA4 is the utf8 encoding for the german letter "ä")

```
  echo preg_replace('~\w~', '@', "a\xC3\xA4b");
```

this echoes "@@¤@" because "\xC3" and "\xA4" were treated as distinct symbols

```
  echo preg_replace('~\w~u', '@', "a\xC3\xA4b");
```

(note the 'u') prints "@@@" because "\xC3\xA4" were treated as a single letter.

Comment: Really? Hmm, I'm not overly proficient with regex strings, if you don't mind I might post some of my preg_ code to see what you think?

Comment: great for u modifier, I didn't know it

Comment: I was getting error when `json_encode`ing a string after calling `preg_replace`, but failing because `preg_replace` converted some UTF-8 characters to the *replacement character*. The `u` modifier saved my day!!! Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. See the question [*preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227) for example.

Comment: To clarify, the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` produces byte offsets rather than character offsets. It's coherent with string handling in PHP but it can be pretty confusing.

Comment: If you use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com), you can use `offset()` or `byteOffset()` methods to get offsets in characters or bytes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use the [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) like [`mb_ereg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php)

Comment: They're the multi-byte version of the POSIX `ereg` functions, though, which aren't exactly the same as the PCRE `preg` functions.

Comment: Ben S you are my hero :)
I just wanted to purify texts and leave äöüß within the text. preg_replace never did this properly, but mb_ereg does!

Comment: as long as you use the /u  modifier, THEY ARE MULTIBYTE SAFE, as long as that multibyte encoding is UTF-8. the /u engine doesn't support any other encodings than UTF-8

Comment: `preg_match` with `/u` modifier works a treat! thank you @hanshenrik

Answer (score 1):

Some of my more complicated preg functions:

(1a) validate username as alphanumeric + underscore:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/',$username)
```

(1b) possible UTF alternative:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/u',$username)
```

(2a) validate email:

```
preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix",$email))
```

(2b) possible UTF alternative:

```
preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ixu",$email))
```

(3a) normalize newlines:

```
preg_replace("/(\n){2,}/","\n\n",$str);
```

(3b) possible UTF alternative:

```
preg_replace("/(\n){2,}/u","\n\n",$str);
```

Do thse changes look alright?

Comment: I believe your email regular expression will allow '..' anywhere in the email address, which is something you need assertions to prevent.