# Sanitize query using preg_replace but allow some special characters

Tags: php, regex

I am sanitizing a query using the following regex. However, I need some special characters to be allowed in the query.

In particular I need to allow: `Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß`

What do I need to change to achieve this?

```
$query = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_\/]/', '', $_GET['destination']);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/[^\w-\p{L}\p{N}\p{Pd}]/
```

This will match anything that's NOT an alphanumeric character (including UTF-8 letters) as well as the dash (-).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really about how to support multibyte characters in preg expressions, see:

- [Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485)
- [preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227)