# Are phps mb_ereg functions safe to use (due to ereg being deprecated)?

Tags: php, deprecated

I just wanted to adapt my code to be compatible to php 5.3 (6.0).
So i wanted to replace all the calls to the **ereg** functions with the corresponding **preg** functions.

But then I saw that the **mb_ereg** function haven't been marked as deprecated. So I am just wondering if it is save to rely on them? Is something known that they will also been declared deprecated soon or is it even a flaw in the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't depend on them.  The **preg** functions are faster, more efficient, much more powerful and naively support UTF8.  I would recommend using the **preg** functions for all of your regex needs.

But to directly answer your question, it does not appear that `mb_ereg` is deprecated...

Comment: The mbstring library is, however, a non-default extension, so it's not exactly guaranteed to be a part of your environment, assuming you're not the one managing it.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace all of your `ereg` with `mb_ereg` if you want quick solution and save your time. `mb_ereg` is not marked as deprecated and it is a direct replacement for `ereg`.

You can rely on it for certain time or longer, we don't know. But if you have some free time, I think should be better, as ircmaxell suggest, to replace all of your `mb_ereg` with `preg`.

Answer (score 2):

`mb_ereg` is not deprecated, but I wouldn't rely on it because it probably is going to be. Besides, PCRE supports UTF-8 via the `u` modifier. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe).