# how to match non-keyboard characters using php?

Tags: php

how can we match non-keyboards characters using php??
characters like-- ♠♣♥♦

i want to check if a data contains non-keyboard characters and if it does i'll have to reject it as per my requirements.

Comment: Maybe you should change perspectives and only accept certain characters like `a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()` etc...

Comment: are you looking to match a list of specific characters, or any non-keyboard character in general?

Comment: What is the thinking behind this, what do you need this for? What about chinese and other alphabets? And eastern european users (who have `Š` on their keyboards) will thank you very much :)

Comment: @Russell Dias: Because as we know, everybody speaks English. I'm not entirely sure what the OP is trying to do, but "only ASCII characters are valid" is a bit naïve (sic!) approach.

Comment: yeah right i want to check if a data contains non-keyboard characters and if it does i'll have to reject it as per my requirements.

Comment: @Spudley : I want to match any non-keyboard character not any specific one.

Comment: @developer — any character that is not on *your* keyboard, not on the *visitors* keyboard (which you can't know), not on *any* keyboard or not on *all* keyboards?

Comment: Hang on, is that an ampersand in that list? What keyboards don't have ampersand characters fairly prominently on them? And can I never have to program on one of them?!

Comment: @David Dorward : - above list is just an example of what i need. The data can contain any keyboard characters PLUS the non-keyboard ones. I just need to check if there's ANY non-keyboard character in my string then i have to reject it. Thats what i want.I hope its clear to you now.

Comment: @developer — no, it isn't. What is a "keyboard character"? It isn't like there is one universal keyboard layout.

Comment: Leeeet's see... */me mashes on his keyboard*: `áščjlkwqAER97é=+ěščáíuihPOeú)` I typed all that on my keyboard (each character with a single keypress, and no, the diacritical marks generally can't be dropped without loss of meaning). Do all those qualify as keyboard characters? (Mind you, I've seen much more exotic layouts, this one is at least mostly ASCII; and even various US keyboard layouts have different keys from each other)

Comment: @all : i basically want just English characters..im not bothered about other languages here...its just those symbols(♠♣♥♦) that we dont usually find on normal keyboards.....i wanted to match them.....anyways my work is done...i took Russell Dias's advice of changing my perspective and so my program accepted only those characters that we want and have neglected all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try

- [`mb_ereg` — Regular expression match with multibyte support](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php)

Example:

```
var_dump( mb_ereg('⊃', "≥⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗") ); // 1
```

You might want to clarify the question to get better answers/examples.

Also see

- [Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe)

Comment: Last living member of the `ereg` family?

Comment: @Russel afaik none of the `mb_ereg*` functions are deprecated yet. Of course, the OP can also enable unicode for the `preg_*` family of functions as explained in that linked question.