# multi-byte function to replace preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, multibyte, multibyte-functions

I'm looking for a multi-byte function to replace `preg_match_all()`. I need one that will give me an array of matched strings, like the `$matches` argument from `preg_match()`. The function `mb_ereg_match()` doesn't seem to do it -- it only gives me a boolean indicating if there were any matches.

Looking at the mb_* functions [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), I don't offhand see anythng that replaces the functionality of `preg_match()`. What do I use?

**Edit** I'm an idiot. I originally posted this question asking for a replacement for `preg_match`, which of course is `ereg_match`. However both those only return the first result. What I wanted was a replacement for `preg_match_all`, which returns all match texts. But anyways, the `u` modifier works in my case for `preg_match_all`, as hakre pointed out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe

Comment: I note your say that `ereg_match()` is a replacement for `preg_match()`. Be aware that PHP's `ereg_` functions are deprecated, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you taken a look into [`mb_ereg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php)?

Additionally, you can pass an UTF-8 encoded string into `preg_match` using the [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which might be the kind of multi-byte support you need. The other option is to encode into UTF-8 and then encode the results back.

See as well an answer to a related question: [Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe/1766546#1766546)

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on the `u` modifier? That's part of the regex?

Comment: Actually it looks like the 4th answer down on that related question has some info about the `u` modifier.

Comment: So I tried it out, and it only seems to return the first match :P Unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You should add your code to your question, so it's actually clear what you tried so far. Take care that the input string is UTF-8 encoded if you're using `preg_match` with the `u` modifier. Then I might be able to spot your error.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that `mb_ereg` returns only the first match string (apparently).

Comment: I'm an idiot. I'm looking for a replacement for `preg_match_all`! :P

Comment: LOL ;), okay. What is the encoding/charset of your string? I ask, because if you have this in UTF-8, you don't need any replacement. If not, you needs to create a replacement function on your own that consists of `mb_ereg...` functions, doing one match after the other.

Comment: The `u` modifier is the correct answer. Avoid the `ereg_` (and `mb_ereg_`) functions because they have been deprecated.

Comment: @hakre I'm not looking to do replacement, but to pull multiple matches out of a large string.

Comment: Find the next match after the offset of the last match + the length of the last match (both 0 at start). Loop until nothing is found any longer. Store matches inside an array.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP: preg_grep manual](http://php.net/preg_grep)

```
$matches = preg_grep('/(needles|to|find)/u', $inputArray);
```

Returns an array indexed using the keys from the input array.

Note the /u modifier which enables multibyte support.

Hope it helps others.