# Why doesn't mb_ereg() detect Arabic characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have an example from PHP.net to detect Arabic. Why doesn't it work?

```
$text = 'بيتر هو صبي.'; // arabic
//$text = 'פיטר הוא ילד.'; // hebrew

mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

if(mb_ereg('[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]', $text)) // arabic range
//if(mb_ereg('[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}]', $text)) // hebrew range
{
    echo "Text has some arabic/hebrew characters.";
}
else
{
    echo "Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.";
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Works for me as well. But why not use `\p{Arabic}` and `\p{Hebrew}` instead? Much more readable.

Comment: @Jon: Though my answer appears to be copied from your comment but I swear I didn't copy. The moment I submitted it I saw your comment saying same thing.

Comment: It should [work as advertised](http://3v4l.org/CA8ms)... assuming that you save the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on character ranges for detecting arabic characters. You can directly use `\p{Arabic}` for detecting Arabic letters:

Following works fine:

```
$text = 'بيتر هو صبي.'; // arabic
//$text = 'פיטר הוא ילד.'; // hebrew
if (preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $text))
    echo "Text has some arabic/hebrew characters.";
else
    echo "Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Text has some arabic/hebrew characters.
```

Comment: There's a small caveat here: `preg_match()` isn't multibyte-safe like `mb_ereg()`. The `u` modifier doesn't change that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe).

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes that's true.

Comment: why still give me Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.