# Determine if PHP installation preg_* functions support multibyte regular expressions

Tags: php, linux, pcre

So according to this stackoverflow answer:

[Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe)

whether or not the preg_* functions support multibyte characters out of the box is dependent on what version of PCRE php was compiled with. On a linux web server, is there a command or bit of PHP code I can run to determine if the PCRE version is >= 8?

Comment: @JosephSible I was wondering if there was a way to do it from the linux command line as well, though admittedly that is not necessarily enough distinction to warrant my question remaning. I will let the community decide that.

Comment: Just run those statements from the command line, like this: `php -r 'echo PCRE_VERSION;'`