# How do I get preg_match 2 digit dot (optional) with Chinese?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I tried to find out preg_match for Chinese character. I can get Chinese character in some way like this

```
preg_match("/^\p{Han}+/u", $message); //$message = '你好';
```

But, sometime two digit number with . in front something like this

```
$message = '01. 你好' //or '21. 你好'
```

So, my preg_match condition is not correct in this message. How do I check this optional two digit with dot?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766485/are-the-php-preg-functions-multibyte-safe)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? extract only Chinese characters?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want only Chinese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/\p{Han}+/gu` like:

```
preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $message,$result);
```

or

```
preg_match_all("/\p{Han}+/u", $message,$result);
```

Comment: I tried with `echo preg_match_all("/^\p{Han}+$/u", "01. 你好");` But, show 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Please note the `^` should be removed since the Chinese characters are not at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a look at the following `php` prototype codes for matching and extracting only Chinese characters? Let me know if it works for you as expected.

```
$ more test.php test2.php
::::::::::::::
test.php
::::::::::::::
<?php
$string = 'abc 123 車飛行 abc 5344';
$pattern = '/[^\p{Han}]/u';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
::::::::::::::
test2.php
::::::::::::::
<?php
$message = "01. 你好";
echo preg_match_all("/^\p{Han}+$/u", $message);
echo "\n";
$message = "你好";
echo preg_match_all("/^\p{Han}+$/u", $message);
echo "\n";
$message = "０１。你好";
echo preg_match_all("/^\p{Han}+$/u", $message);
echo "\n";
?>
```

The output of both codes are:

1) In order to extract only Chinese chars from the String.

```
$ php test.php                                                                                                                                 
車飛行
```

2) In order to validate that the string does contain only Chinese chars.

```
$ php test2.php                                                                                                                                
0
1
0
```

Comment: I tried with `echo preg_match_all("/^\p{Han}+$/u", "01. 你好");` But, show 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @KevinKyaw: do you expect to have `1` for the string `01. 你好`???

Comment: Sounds like I can make tweet test.php. Thanks for your help. :)