# How to get correct list position in multi-byte string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, multibyte, multibyte-functions

I am currently matching HTML using this code:

```
preg_match('/<\/?([a-z]+)[^>]*>|&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;/u', $html, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $position)
```

It matches everything perfect, however if I have a multibyte character, it counts it as 2 characters when giving back the position.

For example the returned `$match` array would give something like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '<br />' (length=6)
      1 => int 132
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'br' (length=2)
      1 => int 133
```

The real number for the `<br />` match is 128, but there are 4 multibyte characters, so it's giving 132. I really thought adding the /u modifier would make it realize what's going on, but no luck there.

Comment: If you're curious what I'm using this for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags

Comment: Does [this][1] helps?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php

Comment: Yeah it's helping. Surprised these threads didn't come up in the suggestions when I was asking

Comment: I actually can correct the position manually by counting the number of mb characters before the point I'm at in my function. I just can't figure a good regex for all "standard" characters on an English keyboard.

Comment: Maybe you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/3432593/107152 "change the encoding to UTF-32 before and then divide the position by 4".

Comment: @Qtax I was able to get it to work based on that link, without dividing somehow. Posting the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at this suggestion from @Qtax:

[UTF-8 characters in preg_match_all (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187615/utf-8-characters-in-preg-match-all-php/3432593#3432593)

And for some more reference, this bug surfaced while using this:
[Truncate text containing HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags)

The gist of the change is this:

```
$orig_utf = 'UTF-8';
$new_utf  = 'UTF-32';

mb_regex_encoding( $new_utf );

$html     = mb_convert_encoding( $html, $new_utf, $orig_utf );
$end_char = mb_convert_encoding( $end_char, $new_utf, $orig_utf );


mb_ereg_search_init( $html );

$pattern = '</?([a-z]+)[^>]*>|&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;';
$pattern = mb_convert_encoding( $pattern, $new_utf, $orig_utf );

while ( $printed < $limit && $tag_match = mb_ereg_search_pos( $pattern, $html ) ) {

  $tag_position = $tag_match[0]/4;
  $tag_length   = $tag_match[1];
  $tag          = mb_substr( $html, $tag_position, $tag_length/4, $new_utf );
  $tag_name     = preg_replace( '/[\s<>\/]+/', '', $tag );

  // Print text leading up to the tag.
  $str = mb_substr($html, $position, $tag_position - $position, $new_utf );

  .......

}
```

Also in reference to the truncate HTML page, there are other neccessary changes:

```
$first_char = mb_substr( $tag, 0, 1, $new_utf );

if ( $first_char == mb_convert_encoding( '&', $new_utf ) ) {
  ...
}
```

My text editor is UTF-8 so if I was comparing the 32 to my file's ampersand, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you need quick fix and don't care about speed:

```
$mb_pos = mb_strlen( substr($string, 0, $pos) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php ?

Comment: It doesn't have the same options I need:
`( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )` vs `( string $pattern , string $string [, array $regs ] )`