# PHP Find all occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: php, string

I need to parse an HTML document and to find all occurrences of string `asdf` in it.

I currently have the HTML loaded into a string variable. I would just like the character position so I can loop through the list to return some data after the string.

The `strpos` function only returns the *first* occurrence. How about returning *all* of them?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Without using regex, something like this should work for returning the string positions:

```
$html = "dddasdfdddasdffff";
$needle = "asdf";
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = array();

while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

// Displays 3 and 10
foreach ($positions as $value) {
    echo $value ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Please be careful using assignments in `if` statements. In this case, your `while` loop didn't work for position `0`. I've updated your answer.

Comment: Excelent fix, but for those needing to find special characters (é, ë, ...) replace the strpos with mb_strpos, otherwise it won't work

Comment: All of those who will reuse this code be careful because your needle may be something like "dd" in which case $lastPos should only increase by one inside the while loop.

Answer (score 24):

You can call the [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function repeatedly until a match is not found. You must specify the offset parameter.

*Note: in the following example, the search continues from the **next** character instead of from the end of previous match. According to this function, `aaaa` contains **three** occurrences of the substring `aa`, not two.*

```
function strpos_all($haystack, $needle) {
    $offset = 0;
    $allpos = array();
    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + 1;
        $allpos[] = $pos;
    }
    return $allpos;
}
print_r(strpos_all("aaa bbb aaa bbb aaa bbb", "aa"));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 17
)
```

Answer (score 17):

Its better to use `substr_count` . Check out on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: this only gives you the count, not their positions as the question asked

Comment: "This function doesn't count overlapped substrings." For string 'abababa' when you look 'aba' it will count only 2 times not 3

Answer (score 4):

```
function getocurence($chaine,$rechercher)
        {
            $lastPos = 0;
            $positions = array();
            while (($lastPos = strpos($chaine, $rechercher, $lastPos))!== false)
            {
                $positions[] = $lastPos;
                $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($rechercher);
            }
            return $positions;
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future readers.  Please edit your answer with the intent to educate thousands of future SO readers and the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using **strpos()** function. The following code is implemented using for loop. This code is quite simple and pretty straight forward.

```
<?php

$str_test = "Hello World! welcome to php";

$count = 0;
$find = "o";
$positions = array();
for($i = 0; $i<strlen($str_test); $i++)
{
     $pos = strpos($str_test, $find, $count);
     if($pos == $count){
           $positions[] = $pos;
     }
     $count++;
}
foreach ($positions as $value) {
    echo '<br/>' .  $value . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match_all` to find *all* occurrences.

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[a-z]+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

For further reference check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: He's looking for string positions, not just matches.  Also he's looking to match "asdf", not [a-z]...

Answer (score 2):

Salman A has a good answer, but remember to make your code multibyte-safe. To get correct positions with UTF-8, use mb_strpos instead of strpos:

```
function strpos_all($haystack, $needle) {
    $offset = 0;
    $allpos = array();
    while (($pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + 1;
        $allpos[] = $pos;
    }
    return $allpos;
}
print_r(strpos_all("aaa bbb aaa bbb aaa bbb", "aa"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `explode()`:

```
public static function allSubStrPos($str, $del)
{
    $searchArray = explode($del, $str);
    unset($searchArray[count($searchArray) - 1]);
    $positionsArray = [];
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($searchArray as $i => $s) {
        array_push($positionsArray, strlen($s) + $index);
        $index += strlen($s) + strlen($del);
    }
    return $positionsArray;
}
```

Comment: The other solutions are easily made case insensitive if needed, this solution is not. It is also about 50% slower on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple **strpos_all()** function.

```
function strpos_all($haystack, $needle_regex)
{
    preg_match_all('/' . $needle_regex . '/', $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return array_map(function ($v) {
        return $v[1];
    }, $matches[0]);
}
```

Usage:
Simple string as needle.

```
$html = "dddasdfdddasdffff";
$needle = "asdf";

$all_positions = strpos_all($html, $needle);
var_dump($all_positions);
```

*Output:*

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Or with regex as needle.

```
$html = "dddasdfdddasdffff";
$needle = "[d]{3}";

$all_positions = strpos_all($html, $needle);
var_dump($all_positions);
```

*Output:*

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Comment: Using regular expressions to look for a substring is not a good approach. Of course you can do it but regex is for more complex scenarios. Using  `strpos` is much simpler in this case and does the job.

Comment: A warning about getting the offset in a string that may have multibyte characters: [preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1725227/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mainString = "dddjmnpfdddjmnpffff";
$needle = "jmnp";
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = array();

while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

// Displays 3 and 10
foreach ($positions as $value) {
    echo $value ."<br />";
}
?>
```