# strpos result 0 stops while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

i need to find the all positions of a particular character in a string. I am using the following code

```
$pos = 0;
 $positions = array();
 while( $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos){      
    $positions[] = $pos;
    $pos = $pos+1;  
 }
```

the problem with this code is that when the `needle` is at location 1,its returns 1 and so doesn't enter the loop.

So i tried the following

```
     $pos = 0;
     $positions = array();
     while( ($pos = strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos) || (strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos)=== 0){        
        $positions[] = $pos;
        $pos = $pos+1;  
     }
```

and,

```
     $pos = 0;
     $positions = array();
     while( ($pos = strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos) || (strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos) != false){        
        $positions[] = $pos;
        $pos = $pos+1;  
     }
```

But nothing seems to be working. Is there any other way.

The two alternative i tried give me

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
```

which i think has more to do with programming error than memory issue.

Plz help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Find all occurrences of a substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737408/php-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `!==` instead of `!=` because zero is considered false so you need to compare by type as well:

```
while($pos = (strpos($haystack,$needle,$pos) !== false){
    $positions[] = $pos;
    $pos++;
}
```

Edit

See the working version of your code from the comment:

```
$positions = array(); 
while( ($pos = strpos('lowly','l',$pos)) !== false){
    $positions[] = $pos; 
    $pos++; 
} 
print_r($positions);
```

See it working [here](http://codepad.org/NxVuCkaB).

Comment: Output 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Comment: I don't think it's caused by that code... What else is happening in your script?

Comment: ` $pos = 0;
 $positions = array();
 while( $pos = (strpos('lowly','l',$pos)) !== false){ 
 $positions[] = $pos;
 $pos++;
 }

print_r($positions);exit;`

Comment: same output with these few lines so must be something with the code.

Comment: Parenthesis in your while condition were wrong, causing the script to never end... See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code..

```
$start = 0;
while ($pos = strpos($string, ',', $start) !== FALSE) {
 $count++;
 $start = $pos + 1;

}
```