# php find multiple occurence of string in string

Tags: php, substr

I have a function which basically retrieves the product id in a description.

```
private function scanForProductIdInDescription($string, $start, $end) {
        $startpos = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);
        if (strpos($string, $start) !== false) {
            $endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos);
            if (strpos($string, $end, $startpos) !== false) {
                return substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
            }
        }
    }
```

i use it as follows:

```
$from = "{PID =";
 $end = "}";
$description = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';
 $product_id = $this->scanForProductIdInDescription($description, $from, $end);
```

at the moment, it only gets the first occurence in the string. I need to find all occurences in the string. The result should be:
$product_id = 340,357;

thanks

Comment: Preg_match? Then you could explode to an array?

Comment: hi atoms thanks for the reply. can you give a sample?

Comment: will write one now

Comment: If you do not wish to use regex then have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737408/php-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: @PhpDev *should be: $product_id = 340,357* - the result is a string or an array?

Comment: @roman it should be an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression instead of `strpos()` is going to be you best bet. I've quickly put the following together which works with your example;

`\{PID\s=([0-9]*)\}`

[You can see a working version here](https://regex101.com/r/KCaGor/2)

Use of this in PHP would look like;

```
$re = '/\{PID\s=([0-9]*)\}/';
$str = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Edit: Edited to return only the actual ID in the matched string. IMO - this is a better solution than the other 2 answers posted as it returns ID's of any length, and only returns ID's matched in the format you've provided.

I've also updated my working example.

Comment: I would put parentheses around `[0-9]*` so you can capture the values immediately :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match_all:

```
$description = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';

preg_match_all('/=([0-9]+)\}/', $description, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "=340}"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "=357}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "340"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "357"
  }
}
```

Comment: at matei how do i get the result to display 340,357

Comment: the result displays {PID = 340},{PID =357}

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) as followed:

```
<?php 


    // $sPattern = '^{PID\s=\d{3}}^';

    // by using a capture group "(" + ")" to enclose the number (\d), you can output just the numbers
    $sPattern = '{PID\s=(\d{3})}';

    $aOutput = array();
    $sString = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';

    preg_match_all($sPattern, $sString, $aOutput);

    // implode the first capture group to a string
    $aOutput = implode(",", $aOutput[1]);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($aOutput);
?>
```

This will output:

```
string(7) "340,357"
```

Comment: cool @atoms. how do i get the result to just print out 340,357

Comment: great. exactly. Thanks @atoms

Answer (score 1):

To get the needed result(**only *PID* numbers**) - use the following approach:

```
$description = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';
preg_match_all("/(?<=\{PID =)\d+(?=\})/", $description, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 340
    [1] => 357
)
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Thank you very much @roman. unforunately i cannot vote because i have a low reputation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can completely avoid the capture group, by using `\K` to restart the fullstring match before your desired numeric substrings.

Code: (Demo: https://3v4l.org/WalUc )

```
$description = 'some text {PID =340}  {PID =357}';
echo implode(',', preg_match_all('~\{PID =\K\d+~', $description, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
```

Output:

```
340,357
```

The benefits to this technique are:

1. Fewer steps for the regex engine to make.
2. No unnecessary bloat in the matches array (`$out`).

Comment: spot on. Thank you!