# In PHP when would a variable assignment return false?

Tags: php, boolean, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

When would a PHP variable assignment return false?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737449/5721273) the following code is suggested

```
while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}
```

... the while loop will end when the assignment...

```
$lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos)
```

...returns false.

When would this assignment return false and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable assignment returns the value you assigned to the variable. So when the `strpos` call returns `false` (when the `$needle` isn't found), so will the assignment, and the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

strpos returns false when the $needle is not found in the $html. You can learn more about the return value of strpos here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php