# Execute a function every time a tag occurs in a string

Tags: php

I have a string, suppose `$string` which contains text to be converted through `nl2br`.
But, these text posts contain links to attachments, like `[attachment=300]` points to an attachment with id `300` (`id` is given through database).

What I want is, that if the string contains the phrase 
`[attachment=*]`(let `*` be any number),
it first fetches the address of file from database and then replaces `[attachment=*]` to for example `<img src="#">`(where `#` is the address of the file with id `*`).

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything or just waiting for code?

Comment: @u_mulder I cant understand what I have to do here. I am kinda newbie in PHP

Comment: this can help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737408/php-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string    . have a look into array_walk  may be not !

Comment: @zod that only answers half my question, I want to spot all occurrences but also convert them into specific words with using databases.

Comment: may be you should try something now and then post  again where you are stuck.         "convert them into specific words with using databases"   otherwise how you explain that

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @Barmar I cant understand how I must use it. Can you post an answer?

Comment: click it man . code is there

Comment: We don't write code for you, we help you fix your code. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: You write a regular expression that matches `[attachment=*]`. The function receives the string that matches the regexp, does the database lookup, and returns the `<img src="#">` string that will be put in its place.

Comment: There are lots of examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I appeared to have been demanding for code, but I just could not find out a way of doing it. So I sat up and FINALLY found out a solution through jquery.

First I str_replaced every `[attachment=` to `<img src=`.
Then this-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each($('.textpost img'), function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var imgid = $(this).attr('src');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/fn/imgfetch.php?i='+imgid,
            success: function(data) {
                var imgaddr = data;
                img.attr('src','med/img/posts/'+imgaddr);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

So glad I finally solved it, and sorry if I failed to understand your advice as I am still learning PHP.