# regex matching words starting with unicode charachter returns unexpected results

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I want to check existence of the word 'açilek' in the context.  Running this:

```
$word = 'açilek';
$article='elma  and  açilek word';
$mat=preg_match('/\b'. $word .'\b/', $article);
var_dump($mat);
```

Succeeds.  This is expected.  However, to match the word 'çilek', the code returns False which is not expected:

```
$word = 'çilek';
$article='elma  and  çilek word';
$mat=preg_match('/\b'. $word .'\b/', $article);
var_dump($mat); //returns false !!!!
```

Additionally, it will match this word if it is a part of a word, also unexpected:

```
$word = 'çilek';
$article='elma  and  açilek word';
$mat=preg_match('/\b'. $word .'\b/', $article);
var_dump($mat); //returns true !!!!
```

Why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_match and UTF-8 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `/u` modifier to make the regex (especially `\b`) Unicode-aware:

```
$mat=preg_match('/\b'. $word .'\b/u', $article);
```

Otherwise, `\b` only considers positions between ASCII alphanumerics and ASCII non-alnums as word boundaries, therefore matching between `a` and `çilek` but not between   and `çilek`.

Answer (score 3):

beware that UTF8 <strike>characters</strike> patterns/metacharacters are not seen as such by the PCRE engine (and may very well break the matching) if you don't provide the "u" switch, as so :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
$mat=preg_match('/\b'. $word .'\b/u', $article);
```

Comment: The solution is correct, the explanation is wrong, though. It's the `\b` anchor that is not taking Unicode word boundaries into account - otherwise you wouldn't see a match with `$mat=preg_match('/\bçilek\b/', 'açilek');`.