# Escape croatian letters in preg match function

Tags: php, regex

I need to include croatian letters like : č ć ž š đ in preg _match. How can i do it ?

I already tried

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zšđčćžA-Z0-9\. \-]*$/", $home)
```

but its not working . I need to escape these characters. Any ideas ?

Thanks,Toni.

Comment: Try adding the `u` Unicode modifier to make your regex multi-byte character friendly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9473867/1117627

Answer (score 0):

may it helps you to exclude (not include) letters?

preg_match("/^[^WAT]*$/", $home)

?