# preg_match convert the input text have sign will become gibberish?

Tags: php, preg-match

I use preg_match I can't find why the input text will become gibberish?  how to solve it?

$input come from loadHTML  I'm not sure is it related this problem

```
$input = $div->nodeValue;
print_r($input);

if (preg_match('/([\$€£])/', $input, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches);
}

£25.00
Array
(
    [0] => �25.00
    [1] => �
    [2] => 25.00
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this discussion : [preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php)

Natively, `preg_match()` doesn't support Unicode string. You have to add the `u` modifier to your regular expression to tell the pcre engine to consider both the expression and the subject string as Unicode strings.

```
$input = '£25.00';
$matches = array();

if (preg_match('/([\$€£])/u', $input, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches); 
}
```

Prints :

```
Array
(
    [0] => £
    [1] => £
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the description!!