# No symbol and number in form validation

Tags: php, validation

I get the surname.Than I do error checking.

```
if (preg_match("/[\d]/",$surname)) {
     $surnameErr = true;
     }
```

The error shown when number is input. However the symbols would not be validated. I ask how to validate all symbols?

Moveover, how to validate all types of country character name with checking no digit and symbols. Thanks.

Comment: try "/[^a-zA-Z]/" or "/[^a-z]/i"

Comment: This would only validate English letter, but others country letter like French or Japanese letter cannot be validated. Is there any other way to validate other country letter?

Comment: That makes it much more difficult. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php

Comment: http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

[**Reference**](http://xregexp.com/plugins/)

```js
var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\p{L}[\\p{L} ']*$");

alert('The first Result(with symbol) Ру@сский = '+ unicodeWord.test("Ру@сский")); //false 

alert('The first Result(without symbol) 日本語 = '+unicodeWord.test("日本語")); //true
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code .

```
 $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z]/';
$surnameErr = preg_match($pattern,$surname);
   if($surnameErr==""){
       $surnameErr =true;
}else{
   $surnameErr =falsee;
}
```