# PHP outputs a strange french character | é = string(3)

Tags: php, utf-8, format

When PHP outputs file names from an FTP folder it produces French characters which are 3 characters long, so when we var_dump:

```
var_dump("é");
```

It shows:

```
string(3)
```

But the actual character should be

```
string(2)
```

The file names are pulled using a Wordpress function

When it's string(3) we can't do a preg_match on it to replace it with a standard ASCII character.

I tried declaring the formatting as UTF-8, but it's already UTF-8. Also tried

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

But the result is garbled text.

Is there anything else we can try? What kind of a character is it?

Comment: This sounds very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1725329/7496329

Comment: Make sure you wrap the filename in the echo with htmlspecialchars - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: `string(1)` is a 1-byte string; UTF-8 is a __multi-byte__ character set, so 1 character does not equate to 1 byte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match and UTF-8 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php)

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right it should be string(2), but for some reason I'm getting string(3) which doesn't work with preg_match, I'm reading the other suggested replies to see if I can use them. Thank you for the comments everyone

Comment: It doesn't look as though you have a UTF-8 `é`: [take a look at the differences between your character and a UTF-8 `é`](https://3v4l.org/FGSrb)

Comment: @MarkBaker wow thank you, i'm definitely keeping this function for future use. Do you know if there's an automatic way to convert these é to their UTF-8 equivalents? Strange, I was using var_dump(mb_detect_encoding("é")) to check the encoding and it was showing UTF-8.

Comment: This is a Unicode "Combining sequence": `65` is `e` "LATIN SMALL LETTER E" (U+0065) and `cc81` is `&#x301;` "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)"

Comment: thank you, do you know if there's a way to automatically convert 65cc81 to c3a9 and then back into a single character string. This probably sounds dumb, but you get the point.

Comment: Just posted an answer to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your character `é` is actually `0x65cc81`, rather than the more usual single Unicode codepoint in UTF-8 `0xc3a9` (`é` LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)). `0x65cc81` is a Unicode "Combining sequence": `0x65` is `e` "LATIN SMALL LETTER E" (U+0065) and `0xcc81` is ́ "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)".

You can convert from the combining sequence to the single codepoint using PHP's [Normalizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php):

```
function strhex($string) {
  $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
  return array_shift($hexstr);
}

$character = "é";
var_dump($character);
var_dump(strhex($character));

$character = Normalizer::normalize($character);

var_dump($character);
var_dump(strhex($character));
```

gives

```
string(3) "é"
string(6) "65cc81"
string(2) "é"
string(4) "c3a9"
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you for your time Mark! and we can run this on whole strings that contain special characters not just single characters

Comment: For those reading this just use Mark's $character = Normalizer::normalize($character); and it will convert them to normal single code point