# PHP writes garbled UTF8 characters to output file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, preg-match-all, hashtag

**[please see below for answer]**

I am using preg_match_all to extract Hashtags from strings,for example:

> #tree#ztdf #n4# night

contains hashtags: tree, ztdf, n4, night

Strings can be any language with any characters, even emojis. Therefore, I enabled the utf-8 flag (/u) in my `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/#([\pL\p{Mn}]+)/u', $media_caption,  $matches);
```

However, some characters are wrongly matched by their byte sequences:

[image]

I read that this is a problem with preg_match_all, utf-8 encoding and php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php). I also tried to add the additional utf-8 flag (*UTF8) from [pcre](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

```php
preg_match_all('(*UTF8)/#([\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $media_caption,  $matches)
```

.. but then I am getting this error

> syntax error, unexpected 'Enabled' T-flag

Anyone knows how I can extract #hashtags with any utf-8 character using `preg_match_all`?

> [Edit]

Ok.. another day, back to the problem: so I realized yesterday, the garbled characters I got after json_decode() are only from looking at the output with Windows command line, which can't handle UTF8. Today I run the program using Git Bash Console and 
- it shows the input to preg_match_all just looking fine in UTF8.
- after this, also no problems: `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n",","), ";", $media_caption);` (replace all linebreaks)
- and no problems after this: `preg_replace('`!\s+!`u', ' ', $media_caption);` (replace multiple space characters with only one)
- now the funny part: it even looks fine after this: `preg_match_all('/#([\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $media_caption,  $matches);`

For example, var_dump for the following string is this in Git Bash:

```
 string(15) "presadebuendía"
```

.. but in written csv/txt it is this: `presadebuend㮡` while this `Embalse de Buendía` is correctly written to the file.

I am currently looking into parts of my code that may mess with character encoding during data processing. So far, I have tried:

- `header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');`
- `header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');`
- `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`
  and replacing fopen with this function:

```php
function utf8_fopen_read($fileName) { 
    $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($fileName)); 
    $handle=fopen("php://memory", "rw"); 
    fwrite($handle, $fc); 
    fseek($handle, 0); 
    return $handle; 
}
```

.. but none of this solved the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using utf-16 or utf-32? Although utf-8 usually works

Comment: once visit this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37391).

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you could try turning it around: Match everything except word boundaries and hash characters: `/#([^\b#]+)/u`

Comment: Strangely, none of your suggestions works: for example this is the correct hashtag as taken from Input #LujánDeCuyo and this is what I got extracted luj㢮decuyo

Comment: @jeroen: `\b` inside a character class means backspace, not word boundary.

Comment: @Toto Really? Didn't know that! What is a word boundary in a character class then?

Comment: @jeroen: There're no possibilities because word boundary is not a character so it can't be included in a character class.

Comment: @Toto Hmmmmm, that kind of makes sense. Too bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much everyone for commenting. I apologize for pointing in the wrong direction: `preg_match_all` and other regex functions were not my problem for messing with the characters. A couple of things confused me (such as Windows command line not being able to output UTF8). In the end, there was only one issue in my code:

- **before writing strings to file, I used `strtolower` function, which reduces everything lowercase, including special characters such as í (\u00e). The solution was to use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) instead, which is limited to alphabetic characters.**

Of course, you couldn't spot this problem because I didn't include the specific code part in my question! During searching for the problem, I also added

- `header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');`
- `header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');`
- `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

to my php-script file, but this doesn't seem to have any effect on my output file. Anyway, solved my problem. Thank you!