# Match a pattern by ignoring different brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I would like to know the first position of a pattern. But it should be found only, if it's not enclosed by with brackets.

Example String: "`This is a (first) test with the first hit`"

I want to know the position of the second `first` => 32. To match it, the `(first)` must be ignored, because it's enclosed in brackets.

**Unfortunately I do not have to ignore round brackets `(` `)` only, I have to ignore square brackets `[` `]` and brace brackets `{` `}` too.**

I tried this:

```
preg_match(
  '/^(.*?)(first)/',
  "This is a (first) test with the first hit",
  $matches
);
$result = strlen( $matches[2] );
```

It works fine, but the result is the position of the first match (11).

So I need to change the `.*?`.

I tried to replace it with `.(?:\(.*?\))*?` in the hope, all characters inside the brackets will be ignored. But this does not match the brackets.

And I can't use negative look ahead `'/(?<!\()first(?!\))/'`, since I have three different bracket types, which have to match open and closing bracket.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:\(first\)|\[first]|{first})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bfirst\b` https://regex101.com/r/IAyxap/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all 3 formats that you don't want using a group with and an alternation and make use of [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to not get those matches. Then match `first` between word boundaries `\b`

```
(?:\(first\)|\[first]|{first})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bfirst\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAyxap/1)

*Example code*

```
$strings = [
    "This is a (first) test with the first hit",
    "This is a (first] test with the first hit"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match(
        '/(?:\(first\)|\[first]|{first})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bfirst\b/',
        $str,
        $matches,
        PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => 32
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => 11
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/pTLGH)

Comment: This answer does not work with UTF-8 strings. A solution for this issue is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php#1725329).